# Startup: Logstash Forwarder

Tags: ssl, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I'm quite confused on how to set up logstash-forwarder. 
I currently have it running on my local host, but am unsure how to set it up to handshake with the remote host. I have a ssl certificate and key, and have the configuration paths to it.

I am confused as far as what should I be installing onto my remote host to get this to execute? Is it just a copy of the ssl key, and certificate, or some type of logstash-forwarder package installation as well?

Answer (score 0):

The remote server would normally be an instance of logstash, using the lumberjack input, where you would specify the SSL parameters.

Comment: Are you saying an instance of logstash as far as installing an entire package with the lumberjack input in the configuration and a daemon running ?